# Varnish - how to serve stale content for all clients while re-fetching?

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I'm using Varnish in front of the backend.

Because the backend is sometimes very slow, I've enabled grace mode to serve stale content for clients. However, with grace mode, there is still one user will need to go to backend and have a very bad user experience.

Is it possible with Varnish to server stale content for ALL users while refreshing the cache?

I've seen some people suggested to use a cron job or script to refresh the cache on local host. This is not an elegant solution because there are so many URLs on our site and it'll be very difficult to manually refresh each of them.

I know the underlying problem is with the backend and we need to fix the problem there. But in the short term, I'm wondering if I can improve response time from Varnish layer?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this (in the average case) in Varnish 3 by using restarts and a helper process.

How you'd write a VCL for it is described here:  (disclosure: my own blog)

http://lassekarstensen.wordpress.com/2012/10/11/varnish-trick-serve-stale-content-while-refetching/

It is fairly convoluted, but works when you have an existing object that just expired.
In (future) Varnish 4 there will be additional VCL hooks that will make such tricks easier.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to serve stale content to all users (during a specified amount of time). You should experiment with the grace and saint mode to set appropriate time limits that suits your application.

Read more here: https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/handling_misbehaving_servers.html